# Explain the output of this program?

Tags: c, argv, argc

What is the output of the following program, if we pass to it the following parameters through the command line:

```
bcd abcd ab abc
```

So, since we pass 4 arguments, `argc` is 4?
We initialize i to 2 and then go and checked `argv`'s from 1 to 3 - my guess would be we add i = 2, and later, in the next iteration i = 3, and that's 5, so the output would be 5?

```
void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char *p, *q; 
    int i = 2, j = 0, k = 0; 

    for (; i < argc; i++)
    {
        p = argv[i-1];
        q = argv[i];

        for (j = 0; *q && *p; j++, p++, q++)
        {
            if (*p != *q)
            {
                break;
            } 
        }

        if (!*p || !*q)
        {
            k += i; 
        }
    } 

    printf("%d",k); 
}
```

Comment: `int main`, not `void main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`argc` is 5.

This program checks each pair of consecutive arguments and counts how many are substrings of each other (either the first is a substring of the second or vice versa):

```
bcd abcd // i = 2
abcd ab  // i = 3, good
ab abc   // i = 4, good
```

In this case, since `i=3` and `i=4` fit the criteria, `k` is 7.

Breaking down the code, the innermost for loop exits if there is a different character or if one string ends.  The line `if (!*p || !*q) k += i;` increases `k` only if one of the strings hit the end.

Comment: Can you explain why is argc 5, and not 4? and what would be argv[0]?

Comment: because the name of the program is argument 1

Comment: @Nicholas the first argument (argv[0]) will always be the invoked program name.  To see this, just create a program that does `printf("%s\n", argv[0]);` and then run it directly.  After that, move it into your path and invoke it.

Comment: @Nicholas yes and the actual program arguments are `argv[1], argv[2], ...`.  The way to loop through the arguments is `for(i=1;i!=argc;++i)`

Comment: @hetepeperfan: No, the name of the program is argument 0.

Comment: @KeithThompson didn't want to confuse people but I agree the first argument is indexed by 0 in `argv`

Comment: The name of the program is `argv[0]`.  Some folks count the first argument as the first parameters _after_ the program name as in `foo 1 2 3`.  Other folk count `foo` as the first argument.  Must be why they are called arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
Can you explain why is argc 5, and not 4? and what would be argv[0]?
```

The `argv[0]` is you program's name. like `a.out` or something else you named. `argv[1] ...` is the params you passed to the program. so `argc` is `1+ paramNumberYouPassed.`